# How should I specify my Premain-class in manifest.mf when starting JVM with -javaagent

Tags: java, instrumentation, agent

I'm currently trying to experiment with Java Instrumentation, and I'm having trouble even starting the JVM with the -javaagent arg and getting a ClassNotFoundException.

I have a simple test project called TestInstrumentation. It has a src folder with a package called testinstrumentation.  Inside is: TestInstrumentation.java and TestAgent.jar.

Here is the contents of my TestAgent.jar's manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: TestAgent
Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
```

TestAgent.java:

```
package testinstrumentation;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class TestAgent {
    public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrument) {
        System.out.println("Java Agent Loaded!");
    }
}
```

TestInstrumentation.java:

```
package testinstrumentation;

public class TestInstrumentation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main Class");
    }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace when I try to run it:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestAgent
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:304)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in my specification of the Premain-class in the manifest.mf of my jar.  Any suggestions as to how I could get this corrected would be appreciated!

Comment: Without going into much detail: Your error message mentions a class `src.testinstrumentation.TestAgent` (note the additional _src_), whereas you showed us a class `testinstrumentation.TestAgent`.

Comment: Edited. Was playing around with the line in the manifest and forgot to change it back.  Still get the same error, just with "TestAgent" as the class not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds more like a packaging issue. In general you do it right: You have to specify the following in your manifest.

```
Premain-Class: testinstrumentation.TestAgent
```

Of course, the testinstrumentation.TestAgent class file should reside in the same jar. From your stacktrace I see that it looks in ***src.testinstrumentation*** however your code is supposed to be put into ***testinstrumentation*** package

I recommend reading the [Not so secret Java agents](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-1) series of tutorials (4 parts). This provides a pretty good overview of capabilities of Java agents.

Comment: Got it to work doing this, thanks!  And yeah, I'm on part 1 of that series of tutorials its pretty interesting so far.